# the enemy are not removed from the scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

i have a problem when my bullet touching the enemy not die i don't know why do i do something wrong ..?

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Bullet)) {
        collisionWithBullet(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }
}

func collisionWithBullet(enemy: SKSpriteNode, bullet: SKSpriteNode){
    bullet.removeFromParent()
    enemy.removeFromParent()
}
```

any body know plz help me
ty

Comment: Are you sure that collisionWithBullet is called every time you have a contact between enemy and a bullet?

Comment: How do you know that bodyA is the enemy and bodyB is the bullet? Couldn't it just as easily be the other way round?

Comment: what u mean caked every time ..? the body A and B change every time so some time the body a be the bullet and some time be the enemy recording to my book but i have no idea why it's not working

Comment: Does the enemy NEVER die or SOMETIMES not die? Have you put some 'print;' statement in didBegiinContact to see if it's every getting called? Have you set your class as the physicsContactDelegate?

Comment: i put NSLog and when they such each other the word shows but when i but remove from parent give me sum bad instructor i don't know why

Comment: Add this right after the if statement and let me know if it works: `else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Bullet) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Enemy)) {
        collisionWithBullet(secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, bullet: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }`

Comment: no not working bad instructor ...!